# If I can render 1 frame without running out of gpu memory, does that mean I can render all scenes?

Tags: rendering

So I had to adjust some stuff like lower texture resolution and lower polys because I kept running out of gpu memore.

I got a frame to render. Once 1 frame renders does that mean the other 2000frames will render? Like does it dump the memory after each frame?

I did notice that after I get that first frame rendered that I can't render again or I run out of gpu memory. I have to close the program and re open to do so.

Is there a cache adjustment I should make?

Answer (score 0):

So far the answer is yes from. I got all my settings for the scene set so that a frame would render then when that frame finished, the rest rendered as well.

I'm sure this is not always the case but this worked for me for my particular scene